# WiFi connection run very slow in Ubuntu 16.04 (USB Stick)

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, usb-modem

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 beside Windows 7.
I use TP-Link TL-WN821n.
Ubuntu normally installed,
seems that USB stick driver was installed automatically.
but the internet connection is very slow (in Windows is normal).
I run connection speed test in Ubuntu it shows:

- 0.90 MB/s - Download
- 1.00 MB/s - Upload

While my connection is 30MB/s Download, 3.0MB/s Upload (speed test in windows shows that).
i tried to search about how to fix the problem, run more than 7 solution and nothing got fixed.
Can anybody help me with that?
Regards,

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: I am having the same slow connection issue with TL-WN821N.   Disable power management, reinstall rtl8192eu driver and still not working.

Lenovo ThinkPad wifi connects to the same AP gives twice the performance.

Answer (score 0):

My TP-Link TL-WN821n often disconnected from the WiFi network and didn't reconnect until I forced it. The following link fixed that issue https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it was resolved reading and doing it like here, blacklisting the driver they said.

[Internet speed really slow in linux but not in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936987/internet-speed-really-slow-in-linux-but-not-in-windows)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.  Another possibility, perhaps more appropriate in this case is to flag the answer as a Duplicate of the answer you refer to.  You need enough reputation to do so, however.