# Internet speed really slow in linux but not in Windows

Tags: networking, wireless

On windows downloading a 100 MB file takes less than a minute while on Linux it is taking me 1 hour.

Why is there such a big difference and what do I do to speed it up?

I am using a wireless network adapter made by belkin and since it is working fine on windows I suspect its some driver issue or something.

I will edit this post with outputs of a command if desired!

--- Output of lsusb ---

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:0990 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro 9000
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:fa50 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 050d:2103 Belkin Components F7D2102 802.11n N300 Micro Wireless Adapter v3000 [Realtek RTL8192CU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

--- Output of lsmod | grep rtl ---

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
rtl8192cu              65536  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              761856  4 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              581632  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Comment: Is it a USB adapter?

Comment: Yea it is a usb 2.0 adapter

Comment: So post the output if `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: Updated the post and btw since I am new to stack overflow, do you recieve notification when I  comment?

Comment: Notifications occur if you mention the name, like this: @Pilot6. Most of the active users also check back frequently, in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check to see if two possibly conflicting drivers are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If you find that both rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu are loaded, then blacklist one:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

After making this change, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: Actualy in my case, neither trl8192 nor rtl8xxxu  are loaded. Or atleast I thinks so because there is a 0 next to those two but not for others. But then they are loaded in other drivers. I will post the output to the question so you are more clear about what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Well that didn't seem to matter I did what you said and it worked! Thank you. Internet speeds are like windows.

Comment: Glad it's working as expected. By the way, if the module is listed, it's loaded. The 0 means something else.

Comment: This is good to know that the new `rt8xxxu` works better. I suspected that. It is not that the drivers conflict. One suggestion: It is better to create a separate `.conf` files for custom blacklists that to append to `blacklist.conf`. It may be overwritten on updates, etc.

Comment: what if I do not have anything listed? my output of `lsmod | grep rtl` is just two lines: ```btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb```

Comment: @olexandr I suggest that you start your own new question.