# Internet speed slow on Ubuntu 18.04.1 with TP-LINK TL-WN821N

Tags: wireless, tp-link

On Windows 10 I get ~90Mbps download and upload, while on Ubuntu 16.04 I get ~9Mbps download and ~1Mbps upload.

Why is there such a big difference and what do I do to speed it up?
The two OS are set up on the same hardware with dualboot.

I am using a wireless network adapter TP-LINK TL-WN821N made by belkin and since it is working fine on Windows I suspect its some driver issue or something.

--- Output of lsusb ---

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0107  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:e207 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

--- Output of lsmod | grep rtl ---

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
mac80211              778240  1 rtl8xxxu
```

--- Content of /etc/modprobe.d/ ---

```
alsa-base.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf
blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf
blacklist-modem.conf
blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist-watchdog.conf
dkms.conf
fbdev-blacklist.conf
intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
iwlwifi.conf
mlx4.conf
nvidia-384_hybrid.conf
nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
```

--- Content of /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf ---

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 led_mode=1 swcrypto=1

remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

**EDIT**:
MTU of the adapter:

```
wlx503eaa683858
MTU:1500
```

**EDIT 1**:

```
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.0.1                                          13.435ms reached
 1:  192.168.0.1                                          13.473ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 1
```

**EDIT 2**:
I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.1 today, but the issue is still present.
My WiFi adapter is listed as disconnected in nmcli after restart and I have to remove/add it again to the USB so it can properly work.

Comment: Is it actually slower, or is one presenting speeds in bits per second, the other bytes per second (which is about 1/10th the speed when including start & stop bits + 8 data bits)

Comment: What's your `MTU`? `ifconfig | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+|MTU:[0-9]+'` What should it be? `tracepath 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @guiverc Yes, it is actually slower. I am using speedtest.net to test both connection speeds.

Comment: @waltinator the MTU is the default 1500 (I think this is the default).
I edit the main post with the MTU

Comment: Did you run `tracepath`? You may have to `sudo apt install iputils-tracepath` first. `tracepath` will tell you the correct MTU.

Comment: @waltinator I updated the initial post with the output from tracepath to 192.168.0.1 (my gateway/router)

Comment: Today it is a bit better on download and terrible on upload:
[link] (http://www.speedtest.net/result/7522846618)

But the main issue persists - on Windows it is very, very faster.

Comment: Upgraded to 18.04.1 today, updated the main post.

Answer (score 6):

I have the exact same problem as your and I solved it by doing this:

1. Install `rtl8192eu` driver from here:

https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux (I used this one)

or here:

https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

2. Add `blacklist rtl8xxxu` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
3. Reboot.

Comment: 5 times faster download, 10 times faster upload! Thanks :)

Comment: about three times faster than the one from lwfinger, but it is still three times slower than on windows :(

Comment: I can confirm this is working. After installing this driver download jumps from 10 to 40, upload from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me were the instructions here:

https://corpocrat.com/2022/04/25/fix-wifi-activation-failed-for-ubuntu/

Just clone the repo and run the file and my connection using the dongle is great now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the TP-Link TL-WN821N v4 and had exactly the same slow DL speed ( UL was fine tested with speednet), so I found this here where they suggest to disable one of the rtl drivers and that did the trick.

[Internet speed really slow in linux but not in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936987/internet-speed-really-slow-in-linux-but-not-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

---

do this first in cmd shell - terminal run these comands

sudo apt list linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git

sudo apt -y install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git

---

then run the intire line below

git clone https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

after this go to the directory ( rtl8192eu-linux ) where the file is cloned and run this shell command

./install_wifi.sh

Comment: It works on Linux Mint 20.3 and also on 21

Comment: Two things first if this is info for the answer EDIT the answer and put it there not as a comment. Second do you know it works on Ubuntu, Mint is not Ubuntu.