# TP-LINK TL-WN821N works at half the Windows speed

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I've had an issue in which the default driver for my Wi-Fi dongle worked twice as slow as on Windows. I have tried many different methods to restore the speed.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0424:2228 Standard Microsystems Corp. 9-in-2 Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0424:2602 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:1c41 HP, Inc HP Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:1d41 HP, Inc HP Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2357:0107 TP-Link TL-WN821N Version 5 RTL8192EU
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
rtl8xxxu              131072  0
mac80211              851968  1 rtl8xxxu
```

Comment: Could you run `lsusb` command, and edit your post with the output please. Also, you can check the kernel version with `uname -a`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok i added that. My kernel is `Linux circl-cb 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` Also forgot to mention that the dongle is v5 but its in the llsusb output

Comment: Could you run `lsmod | grep rtl` and edit the OP please.

Comment: Ok, I did that.

Comment: Well, as per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159415/928088), you may need to install driver from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver`; installation steps are detailed on the repo page. And then may need to `blacklist rtl8xxxu` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Comment: Many USB ports depend on drivers for maximum performance. What is the color of the USB socket the external WiFi adapter is connected into? Please click [edit] and advise if it's black, white, yellow, blue, or red.

Comment: The dongle itself is white so no difference

Comment: I will try to install the driver later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jags I resolved the issue by installing the patched [Realtek driver](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver). The official TP-LINK driver is bad to the point that trying to compile won't work. Simply follow the instruction in README on the repo and it will work in no time.